# Custom Class Loading issues

Tags: java, class, jvm, loader

The issue i am currently working on requires the changes to a class in a dynamic web project be loaded to the JVM without restarting the application. I already know about J Rebel as I tried using it as well(just don't have enough cash to buy it). So I am actually stuck with creating a custom class loader for this project.

My real problem lies with how to detect the change in class file and load the changes into the JVM. So if there exists a tool or API or if someone knows how to go about doing it or any reference links to help with this issue I would be greatly thankful for the same.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why you think you have to build your own ClassLoader? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you mean 'hot deploy of web apps', free containers (Tomcat, Jetty) support it for a long-long time.

Comment: M trying to reload entire classes with complete new object structure, changes to html binding or any change. Hot deployment does not achieve this goal plus it only works in debug mode which i am not interested in doing. The application is huge and is in production already m just trying to decrease the downtime on upgrades

Comment: If your target is to minimize downtime on deployment, you first should consider to change your deployment process and don't mess with the class loader. Maybe you should consider something like blue green deployment (see http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html ). Class loading is a highly complex process and replacing them in a running application is quite involved.

Comment: Hmm real nice thing. Thanks for this idea. gregor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Java 7 you can use NIO.7 `WatchService` See this Oracle [tutorial](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/watching_a_directory_for_changes).

BTW: You shouldn't create your own `ClassLoader`.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what i was looking for and yes i have my own class loader

Answer (score 0):

If you use Tapestry IOC as your [IOC container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control), you get live service reloading for free.

Note that only the actual implementation can be live reloaded, if you want to make changes to the interface, you'll need to restart the application.

- https://tapestry.apache.org/service-implementation-reloading.html
- https://tapestry.apache.org/ioc.html

If you choose to use the [Tapestry web framework](http://tapestry.apache.org/), you can also reload page and component classes on the fly.